# Frama-C make errors (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS): Error: Unbound module Dgraph

Tags: frama-c, ubuntu-16.04

This Frama-C Magnesium-20151002, compilation environment is Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).

```
Ocamlc       src/plugins/gui/debug_manager.cmi
Ocamlc       src/plugins/gui/help_manager.cmi
Ocamlc       src/plugins/gui/property_navigator.cmi
Ocamlc       src/plugins/gui/gui_parameters.cmo
Ocamlc       src/plugins/gui/gtk_helper.cmo
File "src/plugins/gui/gtk_helper.ml", line 1318, characters 9-58:
Error: Unbound module Dgraph
share/Makefile.generic:77: recipe for target 'src/plugins/gui/gtk_helper.cmo' failed
make: *** [src/plugins/gui/gtk_helper.cmo] Error 2
```

Comment: did you install `libocamlgraph-viewer-ocaml-dev`? If I'm not mistaken `Dgraph` is part of the OCamlgraph's gtk bindings, which belongs to a separate Ubuntu package than OCamlgraph's core.

Comment: yes, it worked, you are right.   can u please put it up as a answer and i will +1 for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two debian (hence ubuntu) packages that allow you to compile programs that link against `ocamlgraph`: `libocamlgraph-ocaml-dev` and `libocamlgraph-viewer-ocaml-dev`, the latter containing GUI stuff, that include the `Dgraph` module. While the text-based `frama-c` need only the former, you'll need both to compile the GUI `frama-c-gui`.

Comment: Saved me too. Thanks !